# destinationIndexPath is always nil in func collectionView(_:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath:)

Tags: ios, swift

I am attempting to implement dragging and dropping images from other app (e.g. Safari) into a collectionView in my app. I implemented `collectionView(_:dropSessionDidUpdate:withDestinationIndexPath:)` from UICollectionViewDropDelegate, but destinationIndexPath is always nil.

Anyone knows why?

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession,
                    withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UICollectionViewDropProposal {
    if let indexPath = destinationIndexPath, indexPath.section == 1 {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
    } else {
        return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing the checking of `indexPath = destinationIndexPath, indexPath.section == 1` is simply wrong.

After removing the `if let` and use only `return UICollectionViewDropProposal(operation: .copy, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)`, things work fine.